# how can i render list on the basis of parent_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Project` model with one to many relation with `Responsibility` model. I have created nested route as shown in code. In responsibility `index` I am able to show all responsibilities regardless of project but I want to show only responsibility in index.html.erb which has same `project_id`. How can I do that?

routes.rb

```rb
  resources :projects do
    resources :responsibilities
  end
```

responsibilites_controller.rb

```rb
  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @responsibilities = Responsibility.all
  end
```

I want to show responsibility by project_id not all in index how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 before_action :find_project  

 def index
   @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities
 end  

 private

 def find_project
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
 end
```

This will help you to use `@project` in any of the other actions too and will keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def index
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities
end
```

Comment: It should be `def index` and not just `def`

Comment: I just woke up, fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get all the Responsibilities, So you can try this code also.

```
def index
  @responsibilities = Responsibility.where(project_id: params[:project_id])
end
```